# multer.diskStorage - problem with upload file to folder

Tags: javascript, multer

I have a problem with uploading files to the server with multi.
I read documentation and wrote code according to with documentation, but files still are not upload to folder images

My code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");

const multer = require("multer");
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  desination: "images",
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    console.log(file);
    cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/upload", (req, res) => {
  res.render("upload");
});

app.post("/upload", upload.single("image"), (req, res) => {
  res.send("Image Uploaded");
});

app.listen(3001);
console.log("3001 is the port");
```

Comment: You have to call `POST /upload` request with a file in `image` form field.

Comment: Can you explain? It is new for me.

Comment: Why did you say that "but files still are not upload to folder images"?